# apktool is not generating apk file

Tags: android, apktool

I used apktool 2.0.0 rc4 version and unpackaged CP.apk file using the tool, then modified a file and trying to re-package it using " apktool b CP test.apk " command

and output goes as below , however there is no test.apk in working directory.

```
...\apktool>apktool b CP test.apk
I: Using Apktool 2.0.0-RC3 on CP
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Smaling smali folder into classes.dex...
I: Checking whether resources has changed...
I: Copying raw resources...
I: Building apk file...
I: Copying unknown files/dir...
```

Am I missing anything ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The default output directory is `dist/name.apk`. Thus, in your case the output should be in `CP/dist/OP.apk`.

You can use the `-o,--output <dir>` option to specifiy another output path.

Also, the `test.apk` is redundant and will be ignored.